# Maximum domain of definition of some $\ln$ and $\sqrt{x}$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac {\ln(x+a)}{\sqrt{x}}$. Find the maximum domain of definition and find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>0 \quad\forall x\in D$.

For finding the maximum domain, let's just apply the conditions since $\ln(x)$ is defined in $(0,\infty).$ then:

$$\ln(x+a) \to x + a > 0 \to x > -a$$ then $x\in(-a,\infty).$ and for $\sqrt{x}$ then $x>0$ because it's in the denominator so this means:

$$x\in (-a,\infty) \cap (0,\infty)$$

but this seems not to be enough for my problem.

For the second one...

$f'(x)=\frac {2x-(x+a)\ln(x+a)}{2(x+a)x\sqrt{x}}=0 \to (x+a)\ln(x+a)-2x=0.$ And I get stuck here... maybe should I take a second function $g(x)=(x+a)\ln(x+a) - 2x$ and try to approximate it's roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum domain of definition is given by

- $x+a>0 \iff x >-a$
- $x>0$

then

- if $a\ge 0 \implies D=(0,\infty)$
- if $a< 0 \implies D=(-a,\infty)$

For the second part, we have

$$f(x)>0 \iff x+a>1\iff x>1-a$$

and then

- if $a\ge 0 \implies x>0$ we have that $a\ge 1$
- if $a< 0 \implies x>-a$ we have that the condition is not satisfied for $-a<x<-a+1$

Comment: the correct answer in my book is $x\in(\frac {\left|a\right|-a}{2},\infty)$ for the maximum domain of definition

Comment: Ah ok maybe I've misinterpreted the OP, I fix it!

Comment: so then why is it with that *mean* module?

Comment: @C.Cristi That $\frac{\left|a\right|-a}{2}$ is an equivalent definition, let try with $a>0$ abd with$ a<0$.